# Getting List<String> using Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, string, spring, jdbctemplate

I want to fetch a list of `String` objects from database using Spring `JdbcTemplate`:

This works:

```
List<String> myList = this.logJdbcTemplate.query(this.dbQuery, new Object[] {this.someKey}, new RowMapper() {
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        return resultSet.getString(1);
    }
});
```

with `myList` containing the `Strings` returned from database.

However, the none of the following work:

```
List<String> myList = this.logJdbcTemplate.query(this.dbQuery, new Object[] {this.someKey}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(String.class));

List<String> myList = this.logJdbcTemplate.query(this.dbQuery, new Object[] {this.someKey}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<String>(String.class));

List<String> myList = (List<String>)this.logJdbcTemplate.query(this.dbQuery, new Object[] {this.someKey}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<String>(String.class));
```

Strangely, when I print the `size` of the rulesList after above statement, the `size` returned is 4, which are the number of `Strings` returned from database. However, the list has all blank elements when checking during debug.

What's the issue ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @DaveRanjan: No error. The statement executes successfully. But the list contains blanks instead of the Strings returned. 4 blanks instead of 4 values.

Comment: @Alex R: You guys do realize that this question was asked over a year ago and the other one was asked just 5 months ago.. this question has more answers and more views then the other one... and still this is marked duplicate and not the other one...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a List you try something like this.

```
List<String> data= logJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query,String.class)
```

The reason why your code with `BeanPropertyRowMapper` is not working could be probably because (It's a logical guess) When you provide a bean (say User.class) Spring must be initializing the class (probably using reflection) and then mapping all the fields with the column_name in `ResultSet` provided by the database.

But in case of String.class it is not able to find any field mapping to your `ResultSet`. But it has already created the object and that's why it is return 4 blank objects.

Comment: Hmmm.. sounds logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using `ResultSet` instead of this `BeanPropertyRowMapper` :

```
new ResultSetExtractor<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (rs.next()) {
               String myString = rs.getString("name_of_the_coulmn");
               //do whatever logic with the string : check if it is null or empty ...           
               result.add(myString);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: @Iazarov: Yes. There are alternative solutions. I just want to know what am I doing wrong above ? Why its not working ?

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry. Can you try if  this will change anything : `new BeanPropertyRowMapper<String>(String.class, true)` .